# How to fetch data from database using multiple dropdown in form in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller, routes, html-select

I have a Blade view which is basically a form consists of 3 dropdown value such as Division, District and Upazila:

[image: Blade View]

My index blade looks like below image:

[image: Index Blade]

After the submit button clicked,it shows me page not found. I don't have any idea why it didn't go to controller method.

[image]

**Route:**

```
Route::get('booksnew/allinstbyupazila', [
                'as' => 'admin.booksnew.allinstbyupazila',
                'uses' => 'BooksNewController@allinstbyupazila']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function allinstbyupazila(BooksRequest $request) {

        $module_name = $this->module_name;
        $module_icon = $this->module_icon;
        $module_model = $this->module_model;

        $module_action = "List";

        $title = "Upazila wise Institute List";
        $page_heading = $title;

        $division = $request->division_id;
        $district = $request->district_id;
        $upazila = $request->upazila_id;
        dd($request->all());

        if ($division == '' || $district == '' || $upazila == ''){
            Log::info("'$title' viewed by User:" . Auth::user()->name . '(ID:' . Auth::user()->id . ')');

            return view("backend.$module_name.upazila_input", compact('page_heading', 'title', 'module_name', 'module_icon', 'page_heading', 'module_action'));

        } else {
            if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrator')) {
            
                $$module_name = $module_model::where('division_id', $division)
                    ->where('district_id', $district)
                    ->where('upazila_id', $upazila)
                    ->get();
                
            }else

                return redirect()->back()->with('flash_warning', '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Do not have the permission');

        }

        Log::info("'$title' viewed by User:" . Auth::user()->name . '(ID:' . Auth::user()->id . ')');
        
        return view("backend.$module_name.index", compact('division', 'district','upazila', 'title', 'module_name', "$module_name", 'module_icon', 'page_heading', 'module_action'));
```

I try everything I could but didn't find any solution yet. I just need to fetch data from the dropdown value as parameter and show the fetched data in another Blade view.

Answer (score 0):

The form is going to `admin/booksnew/allinstbyupazila` but your route is set up for `booksnew/allinstbyupazila`. Try changing the route to `admin/booksnew/allinstbyupazila`.

Also, you can try clearing the route cache: `php artisan route:clear`